# Why does my Kali Linux system suddenly restart at odd times?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, reboot, error-handling

My Kali Linux system suddenly rebooted at 19:05. It used to be rebooted at certain times.

Where does the problem come from? Why does this happen?

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 22 19:00:11 sz dbus-daemon[1107]: [session uid=1000 pid=1107] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=1267 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2907171bc-383e-4913-98ef-4e2")
Jun 22 19:00:11 sz dbus-daemon[1107]: [session uid=1000 pid=1107] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Jun 22 19:00:11 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[8466]: Registered thumbnailer atril-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 19:00:11 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[8466]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 19:00:11 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[8466]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 19:00:26 sz kernel: [ 8967.611430] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38238 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 19:01:26 sz kernel: [ 9027.732329] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38520 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 19:02:26 sz kernel: [ 9087.763352] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38802 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 19:03:26 sz kernel: [ 9147.764475] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=39084 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 19:03:44 sz kernel: [ 9165.351804] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.3035] device (eth0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.3192] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.3193] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.3193] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed no lease
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.3197] dhcp6 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908430.4049] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz dbus-daemon[658]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=781 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon")
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz dbus-daemon[658]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 22 19:03:50 sz systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1817] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1818] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1822] policy: auto-activating connection 'SZ' (9a20cc84-47c0-44bd-90e4-36e369b8da15)
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1825] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'SZ' (9a20cc84-47c0-44bd-90e4-36e369b8da15)
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1825] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1828] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1828] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1830] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz kernel: [ 9172.235665] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Jun 22 19:03:51 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908431.1832] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 22 19:03:53 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908433.1016] dhcp6 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5297] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.4
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5332] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5382] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5386] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5394] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5401] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5403] policy: set 'SZ' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.5408] policy: set 'SZ' (eth0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.6221] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 22 19:03:55 sz NetworkManager[781]: <info>  [1655908435.6232] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf0, date = 2021-11-16
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Finished Coldplug All udev Devices.
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Jun 22 19:05:13 sz kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.17.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.3
```

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove`

I ran this command on Kali Linux but the system restarted again at 22:51.

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 22 22:33:47 sz kernel: [ 1659.113575] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=32512 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:34:47 sz kernel: [ 1719.224457] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=33050 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:35:01 sz CRON[2501]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 22:35:47 sz kernel: [ 1779.325362] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=33332 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:36:47 sz kernel: [ 1839.426261] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=33614 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:37:47 sz kernel: [ 1899.517183] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=33896 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:38:47 sz kernel: [ 1959.628058] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=34178 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:39:01 sz CRON[2506]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jun 22 22:39:35 sz systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jun 22 22:39:35 sz systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 22:39:35 sz systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Jun 22 22:39:47 sz kernel: [ 2019.728968] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=34460 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:40:47 sz kernel: [ 2079.839856] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=34742 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:41:47 sz kernel: [ 2139.940752] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35024 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:42:48 sz kernel: [ 2200.051640] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35306 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:43:02 sz dbus-daemon[663]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.57' (uid=1000 pid=2551 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --enable-crashpad")
Jun 22 22:43:02 sz dbus-daemon[663]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
Jun 22 22:43:03 sz gnome-keyring-d[1058]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default_5fkeyring/2, but it's already registered
Jun 22 22:43:48 sz kernel: [ 2260.162534] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35588 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:44:48 sz kernel: [ 2320.273418] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35870 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:45:01 sz CRON[3116]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 22:45:48 sz kernel: [ 2380.384298] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36152 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:46:48 sz kernel: [ 2440.475218] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36434 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:47:48 sz kernel: [ 2500.566132] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36716 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:48:48 sz kernel: [ 2560.667036] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36998 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:49:48 sz kernel: [ 2620.757926] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=37280 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:50:48 sz kernel: [ 2680.868826] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=37562 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 22:52:08 sz systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Jun 22 22:52:08 sz kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf0, date = 2021-11-16
Jun 22 22:52:08 sz kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.17.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.38) #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.17.11-1kali1 (2022-05-30)
Jun 22 22:52:08 sz kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.0-kali3-amd64 root=UUID=c41cc0d2-7e41-4de3-a3e5-5c9096fdd4a6 ro quiet splash
```

The system was restarted for the third time at 23:56.

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=1214 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2907171bc-383e-4913-98ef-4e2")
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz systemd[1032]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz systemd[1032]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=1214 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2907171bc-383e-4913-98ef-4e2")
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer atril-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Jun 22 23:53:56 sz kernel: [ 3725.083054] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=55328 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 23:54:56 sz kernel: [ 3785.184010] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=55610 DF PROTO=2 
Jun 22 23:55:01 sz CRON[7275]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Finished Coldplug All udev Devices.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf0, date = 2021-11-16
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Finished Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.17.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.38) #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.17.11-1kali1 (2022-05-30)
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.0-kali3-amd64 root=UUID=c41cc0d2-7e41-4de3-a3e5-5c9096fdd4a6 ro quiet splash
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] signal: max sigframe size: 2032
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Starting Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files...
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Started Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009c3ff] usable
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009c400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000b3a23fff] usable
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b3a24000-0x00000000b3a5afff] ACPI data
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b3a5b000-0x00000000b3e0ffff] usable
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b3e10000-0x00000000b3e10fff] ACPI NVS
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b3e11000-0x00000000b3e11fff] reserved
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b3e12000-0x00000000c0b30fff] usable
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0b31000-0x00000000c241efff] reserved
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c241f000-0x00000000c2433fff] ACPI data
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c2434000-0x00000000c253afff] usable
Jun 22 23:56:51 sz systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

Reboot time 23:56

`journalctl --since "2022-06-22 23:30"`

```
Jun 22 23:34:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:35:01 sz CRON[4920]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 22 23:35:01 sz CRON[4921]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 23:35:01 sz CRON[4920]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 23:35:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:36:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:37:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:38:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:39:01 sz CRON[5176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 22 23:39:01 sz CRON[5177]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; >
Jun 22 23:39:01 sz CRON[5176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 23:39:16 sz systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jun 22 23:39:16 sz systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 23:39:16 sz systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Jun 22 23:39:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:40:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:41:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:42:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:43:54 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:44:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:45:01 sz CRON[6064]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 22 23:45:01 sz CRON[6065]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 23:45:01 sz CRON[6064]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 23:45:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:46:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:47:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:48:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:49:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:50:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:51:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:52:55 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.>
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz systemd[1032]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz systemd[1032]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' requested by '>
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer atril-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1[6957]: Registered thumbnailer /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
Jun 22 23:53:07 sz dbus-daemon[1054]: [session uid=1000 pid=1054] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Jun 22 23:53:56 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:54:56 sz kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:e8:d0:b9:fc:e0:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PR>
Jun 22 23:55:01 sz CRON[7274]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 22 23:55:01 sz CRON[7275]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 22 23:55:01 sz CRON[7274]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
-- Boot 4722e23160a94d92a7717e1d63c3f81c --
Jun 22 23:56:38 sz kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf0, date = 2021-11-16
Jun 22 23:56:38 sz kernel: Linux version 5.17.0-kali3-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.>
Jun 22 23:56:38 sz kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.0-kali3-amd64 root=UUID=c41cc0d2-7e41-4de3-a3e5-5c9096fdd4a6 ro quiet splash
Jun 22 23:56:38 sz kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
```

The system restarted for the fourth time at 01:54.
I checked the logs after the system was completely booted
There are several errors in the log.

`journalctl --since "2022-06-23 01:30" -p 3 -xb`

```
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR08._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR09._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR10._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR11._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR12._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR13._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR14._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
Jun 23 01:55:36 sz kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR15._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)

Jun 23 01:55:39 sz systemd-udevd[501]: could not read from '/sys/module/pcc_cpufreq/initstate': No such device

Jun 23 01:56:22 sz pulseaudio[950]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.

Jun 23 01:56:36 sz lightdm[1033]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Jun 23 01:56:36 sz pulseaudio[950]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
```

PC hardware : `Intel Core i9-9900K , GIGABYTE 8GB 2666MHz , Asus PRIME H310M-K R2.0 Motherboard , TOSHIBA MK3265GSX`

Previously, the operating system was on `Western Digital 1TB Black` , This problem already existed. Changing the hard drive did not solve the problem.

Comment: Why would you physically install Kali on that machine?

Comment: @cutrightjm Do you think that if I install virtual, I will not have this problem?
I want to install Ubuntu and then install Kali with Kvm. What do you think?

Comment: Does the same problem occur with a general-purpose distribution, e.g. Ubuntu?

Comment: There's nothing in your logs which could indicate that reboots were premeditated which could indicate two possibilities: a HW failure (most likely) or a serious kernel bug (less likely). Check your RAM (memtest86), check/replace your PSU, check your CPU temps, replace the CPU or it could even be a motherboard issue.

Comment: @mehran if you have Ubuntu, why would you want to install Kali? Ubuntu can do everything Kali can do, just install the relevant tools: https://linuxhint.com/install_kali_tools_ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that there are no log messages related to the imminent shutdown just before it happens suggests this could be a hardware-triggered reboot.

The cause might be an intermittent hardware fault, or something like a hardware/firmware emergency measure against overheating. Or if your power supply is old, it might be just barely capable of keeping up with the rapid changes of input current of a modern i9-9900K processor, and ther reboots might be caused by the PSU being unable to keep the voltages at the correct levels and removing the *Power Good* signal as a result. And whenever the *Power Good* signal is lost, the motherboard will trigger an immediate reset to avoid random faults and data corruption.

(Pairing a motherboard using a non-overclockable home/economy H310 chipset with an overclock-ready i9-9900K processor seems kind of a mismatched choice to me, but I guess if the system was built during the COVID chip shortage, you may have picked whatever was available?)

My suggestions:

1. Evaluate your power supply: if it's older than the rest of the system, it might be at the end of its useful life, or unable to react to the rapidly changing power requirements of modern processors. If either seems likely, buy a new power supply. Otherwise, see if you can borrow a known good power supply and see if the problem repeats with that.
2. If replacing the power supply won't remove the problem, it might be a problem with the motherboard.

If the shutdowns don't happen under Windows, then it might be a firmware problem for which Windows "knows" a workaround but Linux doesn't.

Is your system firmware ("BIOS" according to ASUS) up to date?

In Linux, run `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`; in Windows, start a Command Prompt as an administrator and run `wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion`.

The most recent version is 2208, but version 1605 and several older versions before that are described only as "improve system stability", which just might be relevant to the issue.

Comment: I installed Windows today, I did not have this problem.
I think this problem is only with Linux